# Proc reg: checking the best three variables in parallel

Tags: sas, output, regression, linear-regression, sas-studio

I am working on a macro for regressions using the following code:

```
%Macro Regression;

%let index = 1;

%do %until (%Scan(&Var2,&index," ")=);

%let Ind = %Scan(&Var2,&index," ");

ods output SelectionSummary = SelectionSummary;

proc reg data = Regression2 plots = none;

model &Ind = &var / selection = stepwise maxstep=1;

output out = summary R = RSQUARE;

run;

quit;

%if &index = 1 %then %do;

data final;
set selectionsummary;
run;

%end;

%else %do;

data final;
set final selectionsummary;
run;

%end;

%let index = %eval(&Index + 1);

%end;

%mend;

%Regression;
```

This code works and gives me a table which highlights the independent variable that explains with the most variation the dependent variable.

I'm looking for a way to run this but the regression gives me the three best independent variables to explain the dependent variable if it was chosen to be the first variable, for example:

models chosen:

```
GDP = Human Capital
GDP = Working Capital
GDP = Growth

DependentVar Ind1          Ind2            Ind3    Rsq1 Rsq2 Rsq3
GDP          human capital working capital growth  0.76 0.75 0.69
```

or

```
DependentVar Independent1    Rsq
GDP          human capital   0.76
GDP          working capital 0.75
GDP          growth          0.69
```

EDIT:

It would be an absolute bonus if there is a way to put stepwise maxstep = 3 and have the best three independent variable combinations for each dependent variable with the condition that the first independent variable is unique.

TIA.

Comment: How are you defining the `three best independent variables'?

Comment: I guess it depends on how SAS defines them, in a stepwise regression it is chosen based upon which explains the most variance, i.e. has the best R^2

Comment: You're using the default settings? Did you check what that actually is, because it's not R^2, its the F stat. The R squared is a different option. I would highly advise you to explicitly determine your methodology .

Comment: http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_reg_details08.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en#statug_reg003824

Comment: I was using the stepwise regression and then picking out the R^2 from the summary statistics and outputting into a different table

Comment: thank you, i'll read thisnow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try STOP=3 option on your model statement. It will fit the best model with up to three variables. However, it does not work with the stepwise option, but will work with the R^squared option.

```
model &Ind = &var / selection = maxR stop=3;
```

If you only want to consider 3 variable models include start=3 as well.

```
model &Ind = &var / selection = maxR stop=3 start=3;
```

Comment: Quick Q, how would I put the R^2 into a table for comparison? the output is different in this case. my usual code as signalled above doesn't work

Comment: Find the relevant ODS table and capture that is likely the easiest solution. The OUTPUT statement should still generate the R squared values.

Comment: Unfortunately for MaxR the R-squared is only shown as a line before any summary tables, the output table labels are:

Diagnostic Panel

ANOVA